# Connecting an 8-pin graphics card to a 2x6-pin PSU

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-geforce

I have a PSU that connects with 2 6-pin connectors (Xigma Calibre 600W 80+ if it matters). This was connected to my old Nvidia GTX 670 (not sure if the model is accurate, 600 series though).

I just bought the Gigabyte GeForce 1660 which has one 8-pin slot. How can I connect it? I read about several options (connect the 6-pin connector into the 8-pin slot as-is, use a 6-pin to 8-pin adapter, etc.). I'd like to try the "most correct" solution for the PC and the graphics card. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "most correct" solution would be buying a PSU with 8-pin connector.
But looking at the [XCP-A600 spec](https://www.xigmatek.com/product_detail.php?item=89) you should have 2x 6+2 pin connectors on your PSU.